# Partial sort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Is there any built-in JavaScript function to do a [partial sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting)? If not, what is a good way to implement it?

Given an unsorted array of *N* elements, I would like to find *K* elements that are minimal with respect to some weighting function. *K* is much smaller than *N*, so it would be inefficient to sort the whole array and take the first *K* elements.

I would be happy even if there was something non-standard, browser-dependent. I could still fallback to the custom JavaScript implementation.

PS: This is my current custom implementation (without taking a weighting function into account, just sorting the elements as they are for simplicity):

```
function bisect(items, x, lo, hi) {
  var mid;
  if (typeof(lo) == 'undefined') lo = 0;
  if (typeof(hi) == 'undefined') hi = items.length;
  while (lo < hi) {
    mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
    if (x < items[mid]) hi = mid;
    else lo = mid + 1;
  }
  return lo;
}

function insort(items, x) {
  items.splice(bisect(items, x), 0, x);
}

function partialSort(items, k) {
  var smallest = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (smallest.length < k || item < smallest[smallest.length - 1]) {
      insort(smallest, item);
      if (smallest.length > k)
        smallest.splice(k, 1);
    }
  }
  return smallest;
}

console.log(partialSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 1, 9], 3));
```

The algorithm walks through the given array one single time, keeping track of a sorted list of the *k* smallest items so far, using binary search to insert new elements.

Please post alternative solutions if you think they might be faster or more elegant. Timings are very welcome.

Comment: I'm not clear how K works. e.g., are you looking for the top 20%?

Comment: No, it's a constant, usually *K* = 5, whereas *N* could be several thousands.

Comment: So, for example, you have thousands of competitors with scores, and you want to know who got the top 5 scores?

Comment: Yes, that's an appropriate example.

Comment: Do you have a good own implementation already or do you want advise on that?

Comment: Advice on a custom implementation would be good, too. I updated the question accordingly. I think that makes sense, given its title. Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if you think another format for this question might make more sense. (For instance, should I post my own code as an answer?)

Comment: I think your solution is O(N * K * logK) which is a lot better than a full sort (N * logN) for small value of K but worse for big values of K (your splice in insort is O(K) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There's only the [full array `sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), so you will need to use your own implementation.

Little improvement on your code (I had thought of exactly the same algorithm :-)):

```
function partialSort(items, k) {
    var smallest = items.slice(0, k).sort(),
        max = smallest[k-1];
    for (var i = k, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item < max) {
            insort(smallest, item);
            smallest.length = k;
            max = smallest[k-1];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

(Even [seems to be a little faster](http://jsperf.com/partial-sort), I guess due to caching the `max` variable)

Answer (score 4):

For relatively small *k* it can be worth it to implement a Max Heap (by lack of a native one in JavaScript):

- Create a **Max** Heap of the first *k* values
- For each remaining value:

  - If it is less than the root of the heap, replace the root with this value. Otherwise ignore the value. Note that the heap never changes in size.
- Finally sort the heap and return it.

This is in fact an improvement on another idea using a **Min** Heap, but that one needs to heapify the *whole* array, and so will not run as fast. After heapifying the whole array, you just extract *k* times a value from that heap, and return those values.

I have added both solutions to [Bergi's jsperf.com performance tests](https://jsperf.com/partial-sort/4) (copied to [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/pcklz3b84w/1)). For that particular test (5000 array values, k = 10), the Max Heap solution is faster. But this advantage will shrink as *k* is increased.

Here is the code for the Max Heap solution:

```js
// A few Heap-functions that operate on an array
function maxSiftDown(arr, i=0, value=arr[i]) {
    if (i >= arr.length) return;
    while (true) {
        var j = i*2+1;
        if (j+1 < arr.length && arr[j] < arr[j+1]) j++;
        if (j >= arr.length || value >= arr[j]) break;
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        i = j;
    }
    arr[i] = value;
}

function maxHeapify(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length>>1; i--; ) maxSiftDown(arr, i);
    return arr;
}

// The main algorithm
function partialSortWithMaxHeap(items, k) {
    var heap = maxHeapify(items.slice(0, k));
    for (var i = k, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item < heap[0]) maxSiftDown(heap, 0, item);
    }
    return heap.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}

// Sample data & call
var arr = Array.from({length:5000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e5));
   
console.log(partialSortWithMaxHeap(arr, 10));
```

Comment: In the benchmark in my answer, your method was one of the fastest solutions even at high values of K. And even in the case where K was equal to N, your method was about as fast as sorting all the items with `sort`. For example when K and N were both 1e6, your method was about a hundred times faster than the OP's method.

Answer (score 2):

There's no native partial sort function. The closest thing to what you want is [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
function isSmallEnough(element, index, array) {
  return (element <= 10);
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isSmallEnough);
// filtered is [5, 8]
```

The example was borrowed (and slightly modified) from the above link.

Comment: Only problem is that I don't know what the threshold will be in advance. Of course, I could determine the *K*-minimum value *V* first, then filter the array and sort it. Don't know if that's faster than keeping track of the minimum elements while searching for *V* in the first place.

Comment: You might have to iterate over each element once to find out what V is, and then again to filter out each element that's less than V. O(2n) is still much better than you'll get from sorting the whole list:  O(n log n).

Comment: It's certainly faster than sorting everything, but I'm not sure whether it's faster than doing one pass over the array where I remember the *K* minimum elements so far. It doesn't matter in theory (as O(2n)=O(n)), but could make a significant difference in practice. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I made a version than works with objects, like Array.sort(f):

```
function partialSort(items, k,f) {
    function bisect(items, x, lo, hi) {
        var mid;
        if (typeof(lo) == 'undefined') lo = 0;
        if (typeof(hi) == 'undefined') hi = items.length;
        while (lo < hi) {
        mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
        if (0>f(x,items[mid])) hi = mid;
        else lo = mid + 1;
        }
        return lo;
    }

    function insort(items, x) {
        items.splice(bisect(items, x), 0, x);
    }

    var smallest = items.slice(0, k).sort(f),
        max = smallest[k-1];
    for (var i = k, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (0>f(item,max)) {
            insort(smallest, item);
            smallest.length = k;
            max = smallest[k-1];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

// [ { e: 1 }, { e: 1 }, { e: 2 } ]
console.log(partialSort([{e:4},{e:6},{e:1},{e:8},{e:3},{e:1},{e:6},{e:2}],3,(a,b)=>a.e-b.e))
console.log()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code block below, the `nisetamafibo` function keeps an array of the smallest items found so far. The array is sorted and truncated to length K after a certain number of new items have been added to the array, where the number is taken from the Fibonacci sequence so that it is first 1, next 1, then 2, then 3, then 5, and so on. The `nisetamadouble` method doubles the interval after which the array is sorted instead, so that it is first 1, then 2, then 4, and so on. (I also tried the approach that I sorted the array each time after a fixed number of new items like 10 had been added, but it was slower. And I also tried to initialize the array at the start of the function so that I took in a fixed number of the first items of the input and sorted them, but I found that initializing the array with 1 or 0 items was the fastest, so I removed the initialization step.)

The `nisetamainsertion` function uses insertion sort to sort the items. It's very slow at high K-values because insertion sort has quadratic time complexity, but it's fast at K-values of around 10 to 100 or lower, because insertion sort is fast for short arrays. The `nisetamachoose` method chooses `nisetamainsertion` for K-values of 100 or less but `nisetamafibo` otherwise. (In the [Java JDK](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java), the file `DualPivotQuicksort.java` uses insertion sort instead of quicksort for arrays with less than 47 items. A [presentation about sorting algorithms in R](https://www.r-project.org/dsc/2016/slides/ParallelSort.pdf) said that "fastest for < 30 items is insert sort".)

I also tried to implement the quickselect algorithm with and without recursion. The version that didn't use recursion was a bit faster, but both versions were still slow compared to other methods especially in cases where N was high and K was low.

On another Stack Exchange site, someone came up with new variants of the Floyd-Rivest algorithm which were faster than the regular Floyd-Rivest algorithm in C: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284767/kth-selection-routine-floyd-algorithm-489. I tried to implement the variant called `select7MO3` in JavaScript, but it ended up being one of the slowest options in my benchmark.

```
function nisetamafibo(a,k=1){
  let found=[],len=a.length,unsorted=0,biggestfound=Infinity,nextsort=1,prevsort=1,oldsort
  for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(a[i]<biggestfound||i<k){
      found.push(a[i])
      if(++unsorted==nextsort){
        found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
        found=found.slice(0,k)
        biggestfound=found[found.length-1]
        oldsort=nextsort;nextsort+=prevsort;prevsort=oldsort
        unsorted=0
      }
    }
  }
  found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
  return found.slice(0,k)
}

function nisetamadouble(a,k=1){
  let found=[],len=a.length,unsorted=0,biggestfound=Infinity,nextsort=1
  for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(a[i]<biggestfound||i<k){
      found.push(a[i])
      if(++unsorted==nextsort){
        found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
        found=found.slice(0,k)
        biggestfound=found[found.length-1]
        nextsort*=2
        unsorted=0
      }
    }
  }
  found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
  return found.slice(0,k)
}

function nisetamainsertion(a,k=1){
  let found=a.slice(0,k),l=a.length
  found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
  let biggestfound=found[k-1]
  for(let i=0;i<l;i++){
    let v=a[i]
    if(v<biggestfound){
      let insertat=k-1
      for(let j=0;j<k-1;j++)if(v<found[j]||j==i){insertat=j;break}
      for(let j=k-1;j>insertat;j--)found[j]=found[j-1]
      found[insertat]=v
      biggestfound=found[k-1]
    }
  }
  return found
}

function nisetamachoose(a,k=1){
  return k<=100?nisetamainsertion(a,k):nisetamafibo(a,k)
}

function quickselect(a,k,l,r){
  l=l||0
  r=r||a.length-1
  while(true){
    let pivot=a[r],pos=l
    for(let i=l;i<=r;i++)if(a[i]<pivot){let temp=a[i];a[i]=a[pos];a[pos++]=temp}
    let temp=a[r];a[r]=a[pos];a[pos]=temp
    if(pos==k)break
    pos<k?l=pos+1:r=pos-1
  }
}

function quickselectrecursive(a,k,l,r){
  l=l||0
  r=r||a.length-1
  let pivot=a[r],pos=l
  for(let i=l;i<=r;i++)if(a[i]<pivot){let temp=a[i];a[i]=a[pos];a[pos++]=temp}
  let temp=a[r];a[r]=a[pos];a[pos]=temp
  if(pos<k)quickselectrecursive(a,pos+1,r,k)
  if(pos>k)quickselectrecursive(a,l,pos-1,k)
}

function sortslice(a,k){
  a.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
  return a.slice(0,k)
}

// https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284767/kth-selection-routine-floyd-algorithm-489

function select7MO3(a,k){
  let l=0,i,r=a.length-1,rr=r,ll=l
  while(r>l){
    if(a[k]<a[l]){let t=a[l];a[l]=a[k];a[k]=t}
    if(a[r]<a[l]){let t=a[l];a[l]=a[r];a[r]=t}
    if(a[r]<a[k]){let t=a[k];a[k]=a[r];a[r]=t}
    if((r-l)>k){
      let n=r-l+1
      i=k-l+1
      let s=(2*n/3)
      let div=i-n
      let sd=(n*s*(n-s)/n)*(div<0?-1:div>0?1:0)
      ll=Math.max(l,k-i*s/n+sd)
      rr=Math.min(r,k+(n-i)*s/n+sd)
    }
    let pivot=a[k]
    i=l
    let j=r
    let t=a[l];a[l]=a[k];a[k]=t
    if(a[r]>pivot){t=a[r];a[r]=a[l];a[l]=t}
    while(i<j){
      let t=a[i];a[i]=a[j];a[j]=t
      i++
      j--
      while(a[i]<pivot)i++
      while(a[j]>pivot)j--
    }
    if(a[l]==pivot){i--;let t=a[l];a[l]=a[j];a[j]=t}
    else{j++;let t=a[j];a[j]=a[r];a[r]=t}
    if(j<=k)l=j+1
    else if(k<=j)r=j-1
  }
  let out=a.slice(0,k)
  out.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
  return out
}

// OP and Bergi

function bisect(items, x, lo, hi) {
  var mid;
  if (typeof(lo) == 'undefined') lo = 0;
  if (typeof(hi) == 'undefined') hi = items.length;
  while (lo < hi) {
    mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
    if (x < items[mid]) hi = mid;
    else lo = mid + 1;
  }
  return lo;
}

function insort(items, x) {
  items.splice(bisect(items, x), 0, x);
}

function OP(items, k) {
  var smallest = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (smallest.length < k || item < smallest[smallest.length - 1]) {
      insort(smallest, item);
      if (smallest.length > k)
        smallest.splice(k, 1);
    }
  }
  return smallest;
}

function OP_Bergi(items, k) {
    var smallest = items.slice(0, k).sort(),
        max = smallest[k-1];
    for (var i = k, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item < max) {
            insort(smallest, item);
            smallest.length = k;
            max = smallest[k-1];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

// trincot

function maxSiftDown(arr, i=0, value=arr[i]) {
    if (i >= arr.length) return;
    while (true) {
        var j = i*2+1;
        if (j+1 < arr.length && arr[j] < arr[j+1]) j++;
        if (j >= arr.length || value >= arr[j]) break;
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        i = j;
    }
    arr[i] = value;
}

function maxHeapify(arr) {
    for (var i = arr.length>>1; i--; ) maxSiftDown(arr, i);
    return arr;
}

function trincot_MaxHeap(items, k) {
    var heap = maxHeapify(items.slice(0, k));
    for (var i = k, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item < heap[0]) maxSiftDown(heap, 0, item);
    }
    return heap.sort((a,b) => a-b);
}

// DiazJara

function DiazJara(items, k,f) {
    function bisect(items, x, lo, hi) {
        var mid;
        if (typeof(lo) == 'undefined') lo = 0;
        if (typeof(hi) == 'undefined') hi = items.length;
        while (lo < hi) {
        mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
        if (0>f(x,items[mid])) hi = mid;
        else lo = mid + 1;
        }
        return lo;
    }

    function insort(items, x) {
        items.splice(bisect(items, x), 0, x);
    }

    var smallest = items.slice(0, k).sort(f),
        max = smallest[k-1];
    for (var i = k, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (0>f(item,max)) {
            insort(smallest, item);
            smallest.length = k;
            max = smallest[k-1];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}

// benchmark

for(let nk of'31 33 40 42 44 51 53 55 60 62 64 66 71 73 75'.split(' ')){
  let n=parseInt(nk[0]),k0=parseInt(nk[1]),k=10**k0

  let opt=[
    'OP(a,k)',
    'OP_Bergi(a,k)',
    'trincot_MaxHeap(a,k)',
    'DiazJara(a,k,(l,r)=>l-r)',
    'DiazJara(a,k,(l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)',
    'nisetamafibo(a,k)',
    'nisetamadouble(a,k)',
    // 'nisetamainsertion(a,k)', // this would've taken too long to run at K=1e6
    'nisetamachoose(a,k)',
    'quickselect(a,k);a=a.slice(0,k);a.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)',
    'quickselectrecursive(a,k);a=a.slice(0,k);a.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)',
    'select7MO3(a,k);a=a.slice(0,k);a.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)',
    'sortslice(a,k)'
  ]

  let ord=Array.from({length:100},()=>Array(opt.length).fill().map((_,i)=>i)).flat()
  ord.sort(()=>Math.random()-.5)

  for(let x of ord){
    let o=opt[x]
    let a=Array.from({length:10**n},()=>Math.random())
    let t1=process.hrtime.bigint()
    eval(o)
    let t2=process.hrtime.bigint()-t1
    console.log(n+' '+k0+' '+o+' '+t2)
  }
}
```

This shows the median time of a hundred runs in ms and the average rank of each method (where for example 7/4 means that N was 1e7 and K was 1e4):

[image]

For most combinations of N and K, Bergi's modified version of the OP's code was actually slower than the OP's code, even though the OP's code was extremely slow in the case where N and K were both 1e6.

`(l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0` is faster than `(l,r)=>l-r` as you can see by comparing the two versions of Díaz-Jara's method above.

Here's also versions of my `nisetamadouble` and `nisetamainsertion` methods which return the indexes of the smallest items in addition to the values:

```
let a=Array.from({length:1e5},()=>Math.random())
let k=10
let l=a.length

let biggestfound=Infinity,foundind=[],foundval=[]
for(let i=0;i<l;i++){
  let v=a[i]
  if(i<k||v<biggestfound){
    let insertat=k-1
    for(let j=0;j<k-1;j++)if(v<foundval[j]||j==i){insertat=j;break}
    for(let j=k-1;j>insertat;j--){foundind[j]=foundind[j-1];foundval[j]=foundval[j-1]}
    foundind[insertat]=i
    foundval[insertat]=v
    biggestfound=foundval[k-1]
  }
}

console.log(foundind)
console.log(foundval)

function nisetama(a,k=1){
  let found=[],len=a.length,unsorted=0,biggestfound=Infinity,nextsort=1
  for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(a[i]<biggestfound||i<k){
      found.push(a[i])
      if(++unsorted==nextsort){
        found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
        found=found.slice(0,k)
        biggestfound=found[found.length-1]
        nextsort*=2
        unsorted=0
      }
    }
  }
  found.sort((l,r)=>l<r?-1:l>r?1:0)
  return found.slice(0,k)
}

let a2=a
nisetama(a2,k)
biggestfound=a2[k-1],foundind=[]
for(let i=0;i<l;i++)if(a[i]<=biggestfound)foundind.push(i)
foundind.sort((l,r)=>a[l]<a[r]?-1:a[l]>a[r]?1:0)
foundind=foundind.slice(0,k)

console.log(foundind)
console.log(foundval)
```